# How to create InetAddress object in android?

Tags: android, network-programming, inetaddress

HI!

I am writing code that will run in android. I want to get the IP address of my pc i.e connected to the same network. i.e My Phone is connected via wifi and the pc is connected via ethernet cable to the same router. I am able to ping my pc from my phone and vice versa but I am not able to get the ip address or hostname of my pc via code.

I am using this

```
InetAddress inet = InetAddress.getByName( "192.168.0.102");
```

I get network unreachable error.

Kindly help as I am stuck in it for very long.
Thanks and regards

Fas

Answer (score 3):

You can try converting string IP into integer and then construct InetAddress object from bytes containing IP address. Here's the code

```
InetAddress inet = intToInetAddress(ipStringToInt( "192.168.0.102"));

public static int ipStringToInt(String str) {
     int result = 0;
     String[] array = str.split("\\.");
     if (array.length != 4) return 0;
     try {
         result = Integer.parseInt(array[3]);
         result = (result << 8) + Integer.parseInt(array[2]);
         result = (result << 8) + Integer.parseInt(array[1]);
         result = (result << 8) + Integer.parseInt(array[0]);
     } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
         return 0;
     }
     return result;
 }

public static InetAddress intToInetAddress(int hostAddress) {
    InetAddress inetAddress;
    byte[] addressBytes = { (byte)(0xff & hostAddress),
                            (byte)(0xff & (hostAddress >> 8)),
                            (byte)(0xff & (hostAddress >> 16)),
                            (byte)(0xff & (hostAddress >> 24)) };

    try {
       inetAddress = InetAddress.getByAddress(addressBytes);
    } catch(UnknownHostException e) {
       return null;
    }
    return inetAddress;
}
```